# Obtain corresponding column based on another column that matches another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to find matching values from two data frames and return a third value.
For example, if `cpg_symbol["Gene_Symbol"]` corresponds with `diff_meth_kirp_symbol.index`, I want to assign `cpg_symbol.loc["Composite_Element_REF"]` as index.

My code returned an empty dataframe.

```
diff_meth_kirp.index = diff_meth_kirp.merge(cpg_symbol, left_on=diff_meth_kirp.index, right_on="Gene_Symbol")[["Composite_Element_REF"]]
```

Example:

`diff_meth_kirp`

|  | Hello | My | name | is |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Second | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| Third | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| Fourth | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| Fifth | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| Sixth | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |

`cpg_symbol`

|  | Composite_Element_REF | Gene_Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | cg1 | First |
|  | cg2 | Third |
|  | cg3 | Fifth |
|  | cg4 | Seventh |
|  | cg5 | Ninth |
|  | cg6 | First |

Expected output:

|  | Hello | My | name | is |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cg1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| cg2 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| cg3 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| cg6 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well for me but you can try this version:

```
out = (diff_meth_kirp.merge(cpg_symbol.set_index('Gene_Symbol'), 
                            left_index=True, right_index=True)
                     .set_index('Composite_Element_REF')
                     .rename_axis(None).sort_index())
print(out)

# Output
     Hello  My  name  is
cg1      0   1     2   3
cg2      8   9    10  11
cg3     16  17    18  19
cg6      0   1     2   3
```

Input dataframes:

```
data1 = {'Hello': {'First': 0, 'Second': 4, 'Third': 8, 'Fourth': 12, 'Fifth': 16, 'Sixth': 20},
         'My': {'First': 1, 'Second': 5, 'Third': 9, 'Fourth': 13, 'Fifth': 17, 'Sixth': 21}, 
         'name': {'First': 2, 'Second': 6, 'Third': 10, 'Fourth': 14, 'Fifth': 18, 'Sixth': 22},
         'is': {'First': 3, 'Second': 7, 'Third': 11, 'Fourth': 15, 'Fifth': 19, 'Sixth': 23}}
diff_meth_kirp = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Composite_Element_REF': {0: 'cg1', 1: 'cg2', 2: 'cg3', 3: 'cg4', 4: 'cg5', 5: 'cg6'},
         'Gene_Symbol': {0: 'First', 1: 'Third', 2: 'Fifth', 3: 'Seventh', 4: 'Ninth', 5: 'First'}}
cpg_symbol = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```